# Copy filename into a range of length of adjacent column (as filldown) macro

Tags: excel, range, vba

I want to assign a filename (say "CVC") from the first empty cell of column D to the row of that column that matches the last non-empty row of column E (similar to a filldown procedure). However, I'm having problems with the copy method in the last row of code. this is my try:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Long

Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:= _
        "C:\Users\gustavo\Documents\Minambiente\TUA\2015\Consolidar_base\CVC.xlsx")

WBname = Replace(WB.Name, ".xlsx", "") 

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), "D" & lastRow).Value = WBname
```

Right now, my data looks as follows:

```
"column D" ¦ "Column E"
  valueD   ¦   ValueE
  valueD   ¦   ValueE
           ¦   ValueE
           ¦   ValueE
           ¦   ValueE
```

After running the macro, the data would look as follows

```
"column D" ¦ "Column E"
  valueD   ¦   ValueE
  valueD   ¦   ValueE
   CVC     ¦   ValueE
   CVC     ¦   ValueE
   CVC     ¦   ValueE --> Note that what I am coping is the filename CVC
```

Comment: not clear what you are trying to achieve ? can you simulate it manually in an Excel sheet and add it to your post ? it will help us help you

Comment: I just added an example of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding what you are trying to do (i.e. copy `WBName` into every cell in column D, starting from the row after the last used cell in column D and finishing in the row of the last used cell in column E), then this should work:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim lastRowD As Long
Dim lastRowE As Long
Dim WBname As String

Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:= _
        "C:\Users\gustavo\Documents\Minambiente\TUA\2015\Consolidar_base\CVC.xlsx")

WBname = Replace(WB.Name, ".xlsx", "") 

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastRowD = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowE = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(lastRowD + 1, "D"), .Cells(lastRowE, "D")).Value = WBname
End With
```

The line setting the values could alternatively be written as:

```
.Range("D" & (lastRowD + 1) & ":D" & lastRowE).Value = WBname
```